# How to encode utf8 code units to String and read back Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, django-rest-framework, utf-8, emoji

My user input is a string, which also has emojis, so I have converted it to a list of utf8 code units.
When I send this response to server, it stores it as a String

> "[60, 115, 116, 114, 111, 110, 103, 62, 114, 105, 99, 104, 32, 116,
> 101, 120, 116, 240, 159, 152, 137, 240, 159, 152, 137, 240, 159, 152,
> 137, 240, 159, 152, 137, 240, 159, 152, 137, 60, 47, 115, 116, 114,
> 111, 110, 103, 62, 60, 98, 114, 62, 60, 98, 114, 62]"

but when I try to decode this, I cannot as `utf8.decode(CodeUnits)` require a List input but my input is now a String.

I am encoding this String to utf8 using:

```
utf8.encode("My String here");
```

Please let me know if there is some better approach to storing and displaying emojis.
We are using Django Rest Framework in our API.

Comment: no, I am decoding on the mobile app itself, with the server response

Comment: Firstly, I am getting data from the user, then I am showing the data back to him when he clicks submit. When I getting the data from the user, I am calling utf8.encode(myData) and when I am displaying data from server, I am calling utf8.decode to decode the server data. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling your string **temp**, you can convert **temp** to a List by:

```
List<int> intList = List<int>.from(json.decode(temp));
```

Then just convert it to UTF8 using:

```
String result = new Utf8Decoder().convert(intList);
print(result);
```

Result:

```
<strong>rich text</strong><br><br>
```

A more dense answer would be:

```
String result = new Utf8Decoder().convert(List<int>.from(json.decode(temp)))
```

Comment: temp here is the string from the server?

Comment: @Kunal Correct! It is this string:
"[60, 115, 116, 114, 111, 110, 103, 62, 114, 105, 99, 104, 32, 116, 101, 120, 116, 240, 159, 152, 137, 240, 159, 152, 137, 240, 159, 152, 137, 240, 159, 152, 137, 240, 159, 152, 137, 60, 47, 115, 116, 114, 111, 110, 103, 62, 60, 98, 114, 62, 60, 98, 114, 62]"